# Navigation drawer and two pane fragments

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

Im using the navigation drawer, since the menu in the navigation drawer its a listview i though in landscape and using a tablet that will make the navigation "convert" in two pane.
I cant find information about how i can "implement 2 panes" and use navigation drawer. Since im using my adapters and "onSelecetedItem" inside the fragmentActivity i cant make the listview as fragment because the listview handle the "drawer behavior" so im wondering, ¿how i can get a two pane layout and use navigation drawer?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like what you're looking for is [SlidingPaneLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SlidingPaneLayout.html) and not DrawerLayout. From the link:

> SlidingPaneLayout is distinct from a navigation drawer as described in the design guide and should not be used in the same scenarios. SlidingPaneLayout should be thought of only as a way to allow a two-pane layout normally used on larger screens to adapt to smaller screens in a natural way.
>
> ...
>
> Inappropriate uses of SlidingPaneLayout include switching between disparate functions of your app, such as jumping from a social stream view to a view of your personal profile - cases such as this should use the navigation drawer pattern instead. (DrawerLayout implements this pattern.)

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your layout for MainActivity when Landscape on tablets. 
You can put this into `layout-large-land` folder

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="3">
    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_place_tablet"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>`
```